# How close is AES to random oracle model?

Tags: aes, random-oracle-model

I'm wondering if there are any guarantees about AES's randomness in comparison to Random Oracle, but I couldn't find any papers nor publications about it.

Let's say I have a blackbox B which for any input returns either encryption or *random data*

```
B(input){  
  if(hasBeenEncryptedBefore(input)){
     fail();
  }
  with prob. 0.5 returns: "truly random bits from ROM" OR "f(input)"
}
```

where:

```
f(input){
  IV := randomIV();
  key := getKey();
  return IV, AES_ENC(IV, key, input);
}
```

let's assume that getKey() returns the same key for each encyption and randomIV() returns truly random bits from ROM

Is the adversary interacting with B able to determine whether the result comes from ROM or AES?

Comment: AES by itself is a block cipher, or keyed pseudo-random permutation. As such it is deterministic. Are you considering a specific scheme that makes it random? If not, then maybe that's the issue?

Comment: If I'm interacting with blackblox by giving it input and getting in response Truly Random data or encryption of my input with random seeds, would I be able to distinguish in which way blackbox behaves?

Comment: AES uses a key, not a seed. It is possible to build a secure PRNG, such as DRBG-CTR that does use a seed. If seeded well, it should be indistinguishable from random (well, actually, it might provide a better distribution than most TRNG's). I would link to the DRBG (deterministic random bit generator) but NIST is in government shutdown at the moment.

Comment: I made mistake: by seed I meant randomly generated key.

I'm looking for publications that'd describe AES as indistinguishable from random oracle in experiment such as mine

Comment: Yeah, but if you just use AES - the block cipher - with a single random key then you can just send two identical plaintext blocks to distinguish it from a random oracle. If you use a different random key each time then it will be indistinguishable, but you would need as much key information as required to generate pseudo-random output. That's why you need to use AES in some kind of scheme, which you haven't specified.

Comment: "If you use a different random key each time then it will be indistinguishable" - do you know any research/publication/proof of that?

Comment: @wojteo Hi. Think carefully about what you  just said.  If output = function(truly random), then of course it will be indistinguishable if function is non trivial.  But that can't be implemented in static ROM.  The question seems to be mutating...

Comment: _"truly random bits from ROM"_ how is this possible by the very definitions?

Comment: There is of course not a proof. If that was the case then AES could be proven secure. Likewise, I presume that if the output of AES is not considered random for random keys, it would indicate a break of the cipher. I'm having some trouble formalizing that though.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Actually, it seems like proving that shouldn't be hard: if the key is uniformly random and only used once for a single block, then it's basically just an extremely complicated one time pad (the OTP should work with any invertible operation)

Comment: With the number of permutations much higher than the key space, I'm not sure that it is an OTP.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Why wouldn't it be? A single AddRoundKey would make it an OTP.

Comment: @EllaRose You guys are probably right. Not that it matters much for this question, you'd still need as much key data as output data, but yeah. I'll check on the details later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest that I can think of is the [XORP construction which is proven indifferentiable from a random oracle with optimal security bound recently](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/169). To connect to AES, you still need to instantiate random permutations via fixed-key AES.

Answer (score 3):

Like all PRNGs (pseudo random number generators), there can be no guarantee of randomness, so therefore no statement to that effect can exist. However, reasonable randomness for a given application can often be demonstrated.

Following up on Daniel Lemire's [work](https://github.com/lemire/testingRNG): I used 254 p-values (30 corrected) obtained from each of over 512 TestU01 BigCrush results on high and low 32-bits (forward, reversed and byte reversed) of the 64-bit output to perform a (work-in-progress) meta-analysis of AES in counter mode (seeded using SplitMix). I find no evidence that suggest any issues with AES, however BigCrush (thus my meta-analysis) has its limitations.

I believe others (perhaps Vigna/Blackman) have performed Hamming Weight Dependency analysis on it to over a petabyte, but cannot find documentation.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Security) has an AES article with information on security, which is a related topic.

Comment: This interesting but deep discussion about the quality of randomness validation software has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87667/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-rutz-how-close-is-aes-to-random-oracle-model).